# Mapped drive does not work

Tags: windows-server-2012

I mapped a drive on Windows Server 2012 using GPO. 
I did it on local domain policy. 
But that drive still does not map on users' PCs. 
PCs are Windows 8. What can you advise?

Comment: On _local_ domain policy? Or did you mean _Default Domain Policy_?

Comment: Yes, I meant this. Default Domain Policy

Comment: Well do you have any errors in event logs? Can you mount the share via `net use`? What have you tried _at all_?

Comment: I really dont know about net use, so I did not try it.